# How to disable "on mouse stop auto click"

Tags: gnome, mouse

When the mouse stops moving after 1 seconds, it auto clicks, no matter if it is within an application or on desktop.

Does anyone knows how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and put `gnome-mouse-properties`and hit enter.

**2)** Go to Accessibility and uncheck "initiate click..."

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**For Ubuntu 11.10 and later:**

The setting is in Universal Access, Pointing & Clicking tab, Hover Click. Set it to off.