# cursor acting like a single click when it stops moving

Tags: mouse, cursor

I just recently switched from windows 10 the ubuntu linux and I'm having a problem with the cursor. When I move the cursor and stop moving it, it acts like a click when at rest for a second or two after moving it. Is it possible to set the cursor to not do that or no?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're running to better help us troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Depending on the version of Ubuntu you're running, I'd check Universal Access to make sure that the `dwell click` option is disabled (this option has different names depending on version). [More details here](https://askubuntu.com/a/107689/32664).